# n power 0, logarithm

Tags: exponentiation, paradoxes

This might appear like a unusual question, but I'd like to know how you can assume that $n^0 = 1$.

If $y$ is the sum of $n$ multiplied by itself $x-1$ times, then the first power of a number is just the same number with no multiplication, and the $0$th power is $y = n * n^{-1}$ (or a division of $n$ by itself), so $y = 1$.

But the natural logarithm also states that $y = \ln n^x$, so then $y = x \ln n$ and since $x = 0$, $y = 0 \ln n = 0$.

So shouldn't the $0$th power be $0$?

First i'd like to thank everyone who took time to answer, second here is what I Conclude :

It was just a simple basic rule to apply the logarithm rule of a quotient even if the le logarithm expression hold the value 0 inside such as $ln(1)$ = 0 if we divide anything by ln (1) it first apprears to me that we end up having a division by 0 so an an inequality where in fact the priority of operations put us to a substraction of both logarith instead

Comment: Please use MathJax to format mathematics in your question. Take some time to read the Help pages and in particular http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: $y = n^x$ then $\ln y = x \ln n$ , so that $\ln y = 0 * \ln n = 0$, so that $y = e^0 = 1$.What is wrong?... Oh, you've written $y$ instead of $\ln y$. Please rectify that mistake.

Comment: and for the sake of all that is innocent and pure, do not use 3 sets of parantheses when clearly one would suffice.

Comment: **Quote**:" also state that that $y = ln n^x$... then $y = x ln (n).$. so $y = 0 \cdot  ln (n)$ ..." There is no contradiction $\color{blue}{y=ln(n^0)=ln(1)=0}$. **Quote**:"Anything multiply by $0 = 0$ ... Then the power 0 would rather be y=0:" That´s true.

Comment: @callculus does this seems paradoxal to you too ? or is it just me?

Comment: You are using the symbol $y$ for at least two different things and then because you see $y$ in two places you think both symbols refer to the same thing. That is your "paradox".

Comment: @Jnux Mhh, you have to accept that $n^0=1$. It cannot be factorized any more. Only for $n\geq 2$ the term $n^x$ has more than one factor.

Comment: @callculus that is a satysfying answer ! thank you...

Comment: @David K of even if y here is insteand $ln y=ln(n^x)$ apply the qutotient rule and you end up with a weird syntax if you see were im going ..... 
0 = a form that is defyning in itself 0/0

Comment: @Jnux You´re welcome.

Comment: @David K sorry dont apply the quotient rule but rather see it as an expresion worth 0 over an expresion worth 0 *****

Comment: @David K that was my final conclusion... Priority of operations was here my mistake since in logarithm the quotient become a substraction... It take out any eventual possibility of a division by 0... Well done logarithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is coming from the fact that you only applied $\ln$ to the right side of the equation.

Since $y = n^x$, that means the correct way to apply the logarithm would be $$\ln y = \ln n^x$$

And since $\ln n^x = x \ln n$, if $x = 0$, that means $x \ln n = 0$, which makes $\ln y = 0$, or $y = 1$. Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay that help'd but apply quotient rule here $0=ln n^x  /  ln y$ we get something alik this $ln y = ln 1 - ln y$ ln 1 is 0 so we might end up in some sort of negative value ?

Comment: We can't divide both sides by $\ln y$ when $\ln y = 0$.

Comment: so that's were my mistake is... i was rather keeping the $ln(y)$ as an expression so we end up writing that 1 = expresion holding value 0 / expression holding 0 too....

Answer (score -1):

It's just convention. We need a starting point.

I mean, okay, consider $x^1 = x$ for nonzero $x$. Division by $x$ yields $x^0 = 1$, per convention.

Comment: So it would only come from convention then ? just like prior operation as multiply and division before addition and substraction ?

Comment: It's a convention like the convention that tells us $3$ is greater than $2$. It's part of the definition of the operation of exponentiation.

Comment: @David K ... I finaly understood my mistake since I was trying to divide an expression $ln(y)$ holding value 0 by itself it bring me to a division by zero .... here was my mistake ...